# xml of config is incomplete (countries not shown)

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore, configuration, xml, countries

I'm having problems with **showing the countries** in my magento website. When you want to give in you're **billing address** it's **required to give in your country**. The problem is that the countries are empty :

[image]

As you can see the **select list is empty**. But in my backend I have the following **allowed countries**:

[image]

That's my default config and I use it for the website, nl and fr store:

[image]

In my config in my database you can also see it:

```
INSERT INTO `pp_core_config_data` (`config_id`, `scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
VALUES
    (14, 'default', 0, 'general/country/allow', 'AF,AX,AL,DZ,AS,VI,UM,AD,AO,AI,AQ,AG,AR,AM,AW,AU,AZ,BS,BH,BD,BB,BE,BZ,BJ,BM,BT,BO,BA,BW,BV,BR,IO,VG,BN,BG,BF,BI,KH,CA,KY,CF,CL,CN,CX,CC,CO,KM,CG,CD,CK,CR,CU,CY,DK,DJ,DM,DO,DE,EC,EG,SV,GQ,ER,EE,ET,FO,FK,FJ,PH,FI,FR,GF,PF,TF,GA,GM,GE,GH,GI,GD,GR,GL,GP,GU,GT,GG,GN,GW,GY,HT,HM,HN,HU,HK,IS,IE,IN,ID,IQ,IR,IM,IL,IT,CI,JM,JP,YE,JE,JO,CV,CM,KZ,KE,KG,KI,KW,HR,LA,LS,LV,LB,LR,LY,LI,LT,LU,MO,MK,MG,MW,MV,MY,ML,MT,MA,MH,MQ,MR,MU,YT,MX,FM,MD,MC,MN,ME,MS,MZ,MM,NA,NR,NL,AN,NP,NI,NC,NZ,NE,NG,NU,KP,MP,NO,NF,UG,UA,UZ,OM,TL,AT,PK,PW,PS,PA,PG,PY,PE,PN,PL,PT,PR,QA,RO,RU,RW,RE,BL,KN,LC,PM,VC,SB,WS,SM,ST,SA,SN,RS,SC,SL,SG,SH,MF,SI,SK,SD,SO,ES,LK,SR,SJ,SZ,SY,TJ,TW,TZ,TH,TG,TK,TO,TT,TD,CZ,TN,TR,TM,TC,TV,UY,VU,VA,VE,GB,AE,US,VN,WF,EH,BY,ZM,ZW,ZA,GS,KR,SE,CH');
```

When I debug it with xDebug I can see the config variable with an _xml property:

[image]

The path of the config value is `general/country/allow` and the full path (for specific store) is `stores/nl/general/country/allow`.

But when I check `stores/general/` there's only locale and **NOT country**. What could be the reason for this? I'm really stuck with this and I have no clue what's causing this ... .

I'm using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 . (Also maybe good to know: this worked on another server, but when we cloned it to our server it doesn't work anymore ..)

Comment: Just to make it clear. You don't have overrides of this config in Website Scope (Pharmaprofit Website) and/or in Store View Scopes (Francais/Nederlands)

Comment: No, I always use the default config.

Comment: I've found the answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055241/magento-customer-address-country-dropdown-issue) SO topic.

Comment: Then please add the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Please goto Current Configuration Scope: Select **Default Store View**

Now in General - > Countries Options
           Select

```
Default Country -> <select your country>
Allow Country   -> <select all>
```

Select Both CheckBox right side

```
[X] Use Website [STORE VIEW]
```

and SAVE CONFIG it you will get you default country selected and you can choose another country from the list.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just clean `core_config_data` table for that path something like: `delete from core_config_data where path = 'general/country/allow';` then obviously, flush cache. If problem persists you may take a look on the template/block and debug that value.

Are you using some extension there, if so, try to deactivate it?

There is some Javascript involve in this select, so take a look at the browser console too.